# How to set timezone for integration tests

Tags: python, timezone, integration-testing

I am trying to write some integration tests to verify that my application handles 
time properly.  One of the tests that I would like to write is to ensure that timezones 
are handled.  This is the test that I would like to preform:

```
# GIVEN - A system in eastern time with a time written to disk

setSystemTimezone("eastern time")

myTool --write-time-to-disk

timeEastern: str = myTool --get-time # Time is returned as a string - cannot change this

# WHEN - Change timezone to pacific time & read time
setSystemTimezone("eastern time")
timePacific: str = myTool --get-time

# THEN - Time is different by 3 hours
...
```

Since I am writting itegration tests, I don't want to mock specific data functions.  I would 
rather change the timezone of my system, python env or ..?

More info about what I am testing:

- `myTool` is a Click command
- `myTool` Writes data to a remote db

Comment: I don't understand the distinction about integration tests that would mean you would want to avoid mocking?

Comment: @StephenRauch - I am writing "black box" tests.  I am not sure what the tests use internally so I cannot easily mock them

Comment: So the fact that this python-click is immaterial?